# Compile error when another secondary constructor is added

Tags: f#

I have the following type

```
type NumberedCollection(list) =
    let list = list

    new () = NumberedCollection(ResizeArray<string>())
```

It works good as a jellybean for a sweet tooth

But when I add another constructor that takes `seq<string>`

```
type NumberedCollection(list) =
    let list = list

    new () = NumberedCollection(ResizeArray<string>())
    new (col :seq<string>) = NumberedCollection(col.ToList())
```

I get the following compile error

> A unique overload for method 'NumberedCollection' could not be determined based on type information  prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates are: new : col:seq -> NumberedCollection, new : list:`a -> NumberedCollection

But when I specify type information in primary constructor as List, it works.

My question is, in both versions of secondary constructors, the types provided when invoking the primary is List. Why it has inference issues there ? There is no ambiguity that I can see.

Comment: I changed `List` to `ResizeArray` since that is the idiomatic name for that type in F# (and allows your examples to compile without additional includes).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, for the first secondary constructor, the compiler doesn't know whether you want to use the second secondary constructor or the primary constructor.  The compiler defers determining the type of `list` in the primary constructor until it knows which places are calling it, and since `ResizeArray<string>` could be a `seq<string>` it's ambiguous as to which constructor to call for the first secondary constructor.  Notice that in the error message, the type of the parameter to the primary constructor is not defined `` `a -> NumberedCollection ``.